# Django and ajax request: ValueError: Cannot assign must be a instance

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-models

I'm trying to integrate in my django modal an ajax call to modify directly the value of my data. 
In other words I have the following views.py

```
class UpdateCrudUser(View):
    def  get(self, request):
        id1 = request.GET.get('id', None)
        conto1 = request.GET.get('conto', None)

        obj = Materiale.objects.get(id=id1)
        obj.conto = conto1
        obj.save()

        element = {
                'id':obj.id,
                'conto':obj.conto}

        data = {
            'element': element}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

After that I have build before my table as following:

```
{% for element in elements %}
  <tr id="element-{{element.id}}">
  <td class="elementConto userData" name="conto">{{element.conto}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

...
 And after that the modal:

```
<form id="updateUser">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <input class="form-control" id="form-id" type="hidden" name="formId"/>

                  <label for="conto">Conto</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="form-conto" name="formConto"/>
```

Finally the script with the ajax call:

```
function editUser(id) {
  if (id) {
    tr_id = $("#element-" + id);
    conto = $(tr_id).find(".elementConto").text();

    $('#form-id').val(id);
    $('#form-conto').val(conto);
  }
}

$("form#updateUser").submit(function() {
    var idInput = $('input[name="formId"]').val();
    var contoInput = $('input[name="formConto"]').val();
    if (contoInput && tipologiaInput ) {
        // Create Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "crud_ajax_update" %}',
            data: {
                'id': idInput,
                'conto': contoInput,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.element) {
                  updateToUserTabel(data.element);
                }
            }
        });
       } else {
        alert("Vediamo se funziona.");
    }
    $('form#updateUser').trigger("reset");
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```

But If I try to modify using the modal my data, django give me the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Materia Prima'": "Materiale.conto" must be a "Conto" instance.
```

It's possible that this error arises from the model?Becouse conto is a foreingKey:

```
class Materiale(models.Model):
    conto = models.ForeignKey(Conto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Conto(models.Model):
    nome=models.CharField('Nome Conto', max_length=30, blank=True, default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.nome
```

In this case how could I overcome that problem?

Comment: Can you share the `Conto` model?

Comment: I have edited the question and added it after the `Materiale` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UpdateCrudUser`, the variable `conto1` has been assign to be a string, more precisely when you do this: `conto1 = request.GET.get('conto', None)`.

Then, when you instantiate the `Materiale` model (through the `obj` object), you're attempting to set that string to its `conto` field, which expects an object of the `Conto` model, rather than a string.

How to overcome this? Instead of assigning that string to `obj.conto` directly, first make a query to get a `Conto` object by its field `nome`. Something like this in your `UpdateCrudUser` view:

```
obj = Materiale.objects.get(id=id1)
conto_obj, created = Conto.objects.get_or_create(nome=conto1)

obj.conto = conto_obj
```

Note that I used the `get_or_create()` method because in case that the user's input for `Conto` name doesn't match any existent object, this will create a new `Conto` object that then can be assign to the `Materiale` instance that you want to update.

Comment: @revilscano thanks so much for your suggestions. I have got it and with Conto I have solved the error. I have implemented it to all my field but one give me the following error : `registrazioni.models.Tipologia.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Tipologia -- it returned 2!`

Comment: You get that because you have two `Tipologia` objects with the same value for the field that you're using to make the lookup. If that's okay (having two objects with the same value of that field), then use `filter()` instead of `get()` to get those records.

Comment: Okey if I use filter() give me the following error: `ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Tipologia: travi>, <Tipologia: travi>]>": "Materiale.tipologia" must be a "Tipologia" instance`

Comment: I can't tell much about that part because I'm not seeing that code, but if you have those two objects of `Topologia` that match the criteria that you are using, you might want to use an additional parameter to perform the query and have only one object (in which case you can use back `get()` or `Topologia.objects.filter(your_param_should_be=here)[0]`).

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't want to have two records with the same field value for a particular model, make sure you put `unique=True` in the definition of the field in question.

Comment: Thanks you, you are very great :) I solved the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214923/discussion-between-federico-de-marco-and-revliscano).